# How do I know which React event has which TypeScript type for its parameters?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React I can do the following:

```
<input type="file" onChange={onFileSelected} />

function onFileSelected(event: <which type to use here?>) {}
```

But how can I know, which TypeScript type the event parameters have? Actually I found it via Google for this case (`ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`), but how to figure out the event parameters in general? Is there any official documentation on this that I missed or any trick how to figure it out without Google?

Comment: Not sure if there is documentation, but if you use a good IDE and start typing `React.Event` there will be suggestions for different kinds of events. Also their names are mostly intuitive like `React.MouseEvent`, `React.KeyboardEvent`, `React.ChangeEvent`, `React.FormEvent` etc.